GitLab ce and reverse proxy traefik
I have a standalone gitlab ce installed on my server. Its running on complete stock gitlab.rb only the external_url 'https://gitlab.mysubdomain.com'.
I have a task to create simple nginx server inside a docker container and then manage nginx container and standalone gitlab with Traefik. I had no problem making a config for nginx container, plenty of tutorials but I have no actual clue what to do with gitlab. I just started learning reverse proxy and this task just won't let me go.
I do understand that there is something to do with the ports as if I start either gitlab or traefik first the second one will give an error of port 80 being occupied by something else.
In the end i need traefik that is run with a docker compose to manage reverse proxy for nginx container (done already) and gitlab that is accessible via 'https://gitlab.mysubdomain.com'
Help me please to either do the task or point me in a direction i gotta look.
thank you in advance!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
